# Access: How to use IF function to fill out the specific column based on the value from another column

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010, if

In Access database, one column is `Asset Value` that is `currency` format or it could be `numerical`, and second column is `Insured` that is `CheckBox` or it could be a `text format`. I have to create code that will automatically check or mark the Insured column as `Yes` if `Asset Value` column is greater or equal to $2,500.00. So far I have

```
If [Asset Value] >= "2500" Then
[Insured] = "Yes"
End If
```

But it doesn't work. Should I change the `Asset Value` format in `Numerical` and not `Currency`? As well, should I change `Insured` column in `text format` and not `checkbox`? And where should I type in the code so it will work? I tried in Visual Basic for Applications, but I'm not sure what specific field should I write the code or select it.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quote marks around both the 2500 and Yes
(because they are not text values)

Also for (Yes/No) checkbox fields, you can
use the reserved words True or False (without any quotes)
(or also the equivalent numerical value for checkboxes of -1 or 0)

```
If [Asset Value] >= 2500 Then
   [Insured] = True
End If
```